# How to manage button inside tableview in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, button, tableview

I have problem with tableview. I have one tableview and in table cell create button and set title NO.

When user touch button at that time set button title YES. But how to know that how many button are there with title YES.

[image]

Please help me.........

Comment: store indexpaths of button with name YES

Comment: You can create a `NSMutableDictionary` with key as indexPath.row and value as either yes or no. Update your dictionary everytime the button's `IBAction` is called.

Comment: Please, post a code example of what you've already tried to do

Comment: @NSNoob NSMutableIndexSet is a better data structure than a dictionary for this purpose

Comment: @Paulw11 I didn't know. As you see, NSNoob here.

Answer (score 2):

Try following solution.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    ObjectClass *obj = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text =  obj.someTextPropertyValue;

    // ----- If you have custom cell, then omit this part -----
    UIButton *btnYesNo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnYesNo.frame = CGRectMake(290, 0, 30, 30);
    [btnYesNo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plus_img.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnYesNo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plus_img.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [btnYesNo setTitle:@"No" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnYesNo setTitle:@"Yes" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btnYesNo];
    // --------------------

    btnYesNo.selected = obj.selected; // At first, this selected property of type add to your object class
    btnYesNo.tag = indexPath.row;
    [btnYesNo addTarget:self action:@selector(changeState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}
```

Either of following ways, you can change state of your button,

```
// -------First way --> Either change state on select row --------
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // ----- If you have custom cell, then omit this part -----
    for (id view in cell.contentView.subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)view;
            if (btn.selected)
            {
               btn.selected = FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
               btn.selected = TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    // ------------------------
    // ----- Have custom cell, then directly use----
    if (cell.btnYesNo.selected)
    {
        cell.btnYesNo.selected = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.btnYesNo.selected = TRUE;
    }
     //-----------------------------------------

    ObjectClass *obj = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    obj.selected = sender.selected;
    // Call web service to update status Or update recoed in database
}
```

Or on button click

```
// ---------- Or you want to change state only on button click -------
- (void)changeState:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (sender.selected)
    {
        sender.selected = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        sender.selected = TRUE;
    }

    ObjectClass *obj = [yourArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    obj.selected = sender.selected;
    // Call web service to update status Or update recoed in database
}
```