# How to set a tag value to UIButton in UITableView Cell in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I used Custom cell and created `UIButton` in `UITableViewCell`. I want to change the button states as below screenshot. Am new to Xcode can anybody guide me. Thanks in advance

[image]

Here is my code

PrivacyCell.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *on_offBtn;

- (IBAction)on_offBtnAction:(UIButton *)sender;

@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL on_image;

@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL off_image;
```

PrivacyCell.m

```
#import "PrivacyCell.h"

- (IBAction)on_offBtnAction:(UIButton *)sender {
     if (on_image == YES) {
         [_on_offBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on_icon.png"]                      forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         on_image = NO;
     } else if (on_image == NO)  {
         [_on_offBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         on_image = YES;
     }
}
```

Comment: how do you populate you UITableView ?

Comment: please add your `cellForRow` part

Comment: Show your `cellforRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

In `cellforRowAtIndexPath` set button property Like

```
btn.tag = indexPath.row;
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

And change its state in click event

```
- (IBAction)on_offBtnAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
     sender.selected = !sender.selected;
     // [yourTableVew reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Complete solution is here. Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33432578/how-to-manage-button-inside-tableview-in-ios/33435863#33435863

Comment: Am using CustomCell to display btn.How should i set

Comment: [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

Answer (score 0):

You can set a tag here

PrivacyCell.m

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
       on_offBtn.tag = 100;
    }
    return self;
 }
```

and then you can use

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
button.selected = true;
```

but you can also use your property.

Answer (score 0):

even you can set tag to `UIButton` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   PrivacyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[PrivacyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
      // or you can use custom method for init
   }

   ...

   cell.on_offBtn.tag = indexPath.row;

   ...

   return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a IBAction for the button in UITableViewCell from storyboard and then whenever your click on that button this method will be called. You will get the index of the button you clicked and you can perform any task accordingly.

This helps if you have multiple buttons on a tabelViewCell.

```
- (IBAction)tidesButtonAction:(id)sender
{
     CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero
                                       toView:self.tableView];
     NSIndexPath *tappedIP = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
     NSString *text = [tidesURLArray objectAtIndex:tappedIP.row];
}
```